# Map.computeIfPresent() to initialize a List in Java

Tags: java, java-8, maps

I have the following code:

```
for (String val: values) {
     EnumType type = EnumType.get(val);
     if (type != null) {
         String key = type.name();
         if (key.equals("camp2"))
                key = "camp1";
         ArrayList<String> tempList= mapN.get(key); //1
         if (tempList == null) {  // 2
            tempList = new ArrayList<>();
         }
         tempList.add(val);
         mapN.put(key, tempList);  //3
    }
}
```

where mapN, and valies are:

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mapN
ArrayList<String>  values
type is an enum
```

And I have sonar, and sonar tell me that in the values with //  `1,2,3` I need to use:

Map.computeIfPresent()

But I have reading about this topic, and I didn't find the way to change my code.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can shorten that to:

```
values.forEach(val -> {
     EnumType type = EnumType.get(val);
     if(type != null){
          String key = type.name();
          if (key.equals("camp2"))
               key = "camp1";
          mapN.computeIfAbsent(key, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(val);
     }
});
```

Comment: excuseme, I use an if in the for, I forgot submit the if in my question :(

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle that does not really change the problem... see edit

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle did you try that code btw within your code base?

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle you don't need to use lambdas here. You can stick with your for loop. (Eugene and I disagree on the use of forEach; I just want to point out that if you aren't comfortable with lambdas, you don't have to use one).

Comment: Agreed on the part of being comfortable, since in such blocks neither is lambda improving the readability of the code nor is it providing any performance enhancement IMHO.

Comment: @nullpointer I don't have a strong opinion here about this, I really don't care, could be easily a loop too. A loop would be faster too, agreed, since there would be no need to build that `Consumer` via `.forEach`. It's something *I like* to do (sometimes)...  It's interesting that python lambdas don't allow this to begin with.

Comment: @Eugene I'd like to know if I my answer implements your logic correctly. (I just wrote down the code that just came up in my mind while reading yours, so I want to confirm if I am indeed able to refactor code by instinct.)

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of @Eugene's answer yields:

```
values.forEach(val -> Optional.of(val)
   // get corresponding type, if it exists
   .map(EnumType::get)
   // get key
   .map(EnumType::name)
   // handle key == "camp2" scenario
   .map(key -> key.equals("camp2")
     ? "camp1"
     : key
   )
   // add val to map value list
   .ifPresent(key -> mapN.computeIfAbsent(
     key,
     x -> new ArrayList<>()
   ).add(val))
});
```